# Database design issue

Tags: database-design, postgresql

I have a table Orders. Each order can have the same product multiple times. **Quantity is not enough** as each product may have different preferences!
So i am wondering what is better to do...

PK-id  order id product id ? Primary key is PK-id

or
**Orders Table**
(Order-id ,orderline)  as PK..

Then another table
**Orderlines**
(Order-id, orderline,  productid)  as PK

And then
**OrderLinesPreferences**
(Order-id ,orderline, productid, preferenceid  )as PK  ?

I wonder whether this approach is ok .Also i dont know what  i should i do about indexing in order not to get slow when records are many. I am using postgresql..
 For example in table OrderLinesPreferences  a  where order-id=1 and productid=10; would be fast or would do a full table lookup ?

Comment: Gievn that an important aspect of database design is the naming of objects it is depressing to see just how many questioners have tiltled their question "Database design issue".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a comment made by @OP to an answer by dnuttle, I would say the situation calls for items and sub-items, all from a list of basic items.

So:

```
PRODUCT
  product_id PK
, description
, ...

OPTIONAL_ITEM
  option_id PK
, description
, ...

ORDER
  order_id PK
, date_taken...

ORDER_ITEM
  order_id PK, FK
, item_number PK     // Or use a surrogate as PK, if you like
, product_id FK
, quantity

ORDER_ITEM_OPTION
  order_id PK, FK
, item_number, PK, FK  // Order and item FK to ORDER_ITEM
, option_id, PK, FK    // FK to OPTIONAL_ITEM
, quantity
```

This gives you what you need to have an order with the same item multiple times and 0 or more options applied to each item, as in a coffee with different amounts of cream and sugar etc. as per OP's requirement.

Comment: i think that this is what i am going to  do.  However any tip how to generate item_number?Maybe i should i avoid deleting ? Just disable? Because it seems messy when multiple people work on an order or trying to modify it.. How is it going to know which item_number to use?

Comment: @Parhs, The item_number can be system generated, like a sequence number.  Don't let users enter this manually.  The user interface doesn't even need to show this number if you don't want to.  Instead you can just show the order_items in a list.  The item_number can be in a hidden field so that the system knows which line is which, but users just know what they are working on by where it is on the screen, if you know what I mean?

Comment: yes,however the problem is: if i set it to sequence auto number then it wont start from 1 for each order. This isnt a true problem but dont know whether this is good practice. However i think that ordering should be based also on other criteria not this number only. So is it ok to set it to auto increment number although it isnt possible to start from 1 for each order ?

Comment: also(correct me if i am wrong) if orderitem is auto-number then the reason not to set it as PK solo is for performance reasons?

Comment: You have 2 choices for the PK of order item.  You could use a single (meaningless) auto-number which would be unique across all orders.  If you do this, then you don't need order_id and item_number as a composite PK.  You still need both for columns for the FK to ORDER and as an external id for the item.  Your other option is to use the composite PK (order_id and item_number are PK together).  Either way, your item_number can be set by your code and can start at 1 for every order or you can use auto number.  If the order number is hidden from the user it doesn't matter whether it starts at 1.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by "each product may have different preferences."  Does this mean that each line in an order may have different variations for the same product?  So you might buy a product once, a shirt, say, with a size of large, and another time, with a size of medium?  In that case, this sounds like products vs. SKUs to me.  You would need a "sub-product" or "SKU" table that would be linked to the product table, if that is the case.  Then the lines in your order would be linked to SKUs, rather than products.  It's possible to link both to the order lines, but not necessary.

Comment: well yes. It for foods. Like ordering a coffee. The amount of milk etc. Combinations are too many(to make subproducts).And two people may order the same coffee but with different preferences..

Comment: +1 for making a good point about SKUs and where the FK belongs in such a situation, even if that turns out not to be applicable to OP's business rules.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the designs that you showed (as I read them; your notation is a little confusing) is what I would suggest. In situations where `OrderID, ProductID` does not uniquely identify an order item (as is the case when the same product can be ordered multiple times on a given order), then the common practice is to adopt a surrogate key in the detail table. For example, the schema would look like:

```
Order (note here that table names, by convention, are in singular form)
----------
OrderID
CustomerID
...
etc.
PK is OrderID

OrderItem
-----------
OrderID
ItemNumber
ProductID
Quantity
...
etc.
PK is OrderID, ItemNumber
```

`ItemNumber` would be a sequentially-numbered field that starts over for each `OrderID`.

As for how to store your preferences, you don't give enough information to answer that adequately. If each individual order item would have exactly one "preference", then you can simply include it in the `OrderItem` table. If each order item could have a variable number of preferences, then you would need something like:

```
OrderItemPreference
------------
OrderID
ItemNumber
... preference information
PK is OrderID, ItemNumber, and something to uniquely identify the preference
```

Comment: hmm this looks a little like my solution, i added more collumns than needed in PK.I want 0-n preferences for each product

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've got in my head:

```
| OrderId | ProductKey | ProductPrefKey | Qty |
```

If you have to present the invoice in a certain order, you'll need to add a line identifier, but otherwise you can ignore it. You can make the primary key be OrderId, ProductKey, ProductPrefKey and that will provide you with fast access by order.

Since this seems to be a new implementation, keep in mind the following: prices on products often change over time (as do customer addresses, coupons, etc.), and once you complete an invoice, you'll want to keep a historical record of that. That can be done by changing the ProductKey every time you change any detail about the item, or you'll need some sort of archival system that includes all the historical detail that is relevant to an invoice.

Comment: Yes this is a solution i dont know why i havent thought of this. In case there isnt a preference null would be ok i think. Most of the times there will be a preference.in case of composite PKs  that are indexed you mean that searching by oderid and productkey would be indexed too and not full table lookup?

Comment: Also when i have 100.000 + orders searching by orderid would be indexed? i hope that it wont take over a second...

Comment: When using OrderId as the first column of a primary key, you search time against that field is O(log N) -- or 16 seeks against memory for 100,000 entries. That will definitely complete in under a second on any setup that isn't being horribly overloaded. If that table consists of 3 64-bit integers and a 32 bit for the quantity, the whole thing will fit within 3MB of memory before you count in the page overhead.